# Was singer Taio Cruz's birth name Adetayo Ayowale Onile-Ere?

Tags: united-kingdom, celebrities

Singer [Taio Cruz](http://taiocruz.com/biography.html) has a web page that lists his full name as follows:

> Jacob Taio Cruz (Pronounced as ‘Tie’ ‘O’)

In several other places, his birth name is listed differently:

- [Music Brainz](http://musicbrainz.org/artist/ba7d2626-38ce-4859-8495-bdb5732715c4)

  > Legal name: Adetayo Ayowale Onile-Ere, Jacob Milan Taio Cruz
- [Billboard](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rOA5W_BoYGIC&lpg=PA24&hl=sv&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q&f=false)

  > he grew up as Adetayo Onile-Ere
- [ISNI](http://isni-url.oclc.nl/isni/0000000110084242)

  > Related identities: Onile-Ere, Adetayo Ayowale (Wirklicher Name; other identity, same person)
- Cover of the single [Your Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Your_Game)

  > [image: Cover showing the name T. Onile-Ere]  <sup>[src](http://ia801509.us.archive.org/24/items/mbid-8616e5ac-5c49-401f-9992-e2db8db2bf5e/mbid-8616e5ac-5c49-401f-9992-e2db8db2bf5e-13232491672.jpg)</sup>
- [Family Search Birth Registration](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QV47-L83N) claimed to be his

  > Name: Adetayo Ayowale O A Onile-Ere
- [Music Brainz claim](https://blog.musicbrainz.org/2016/03/08/beware-of-the-web-sherriff/) they were asked by [Web Sheriff](http://www.websheriff.com/) to remove the name Adetayo Ayowale Onile-Ere from their site, and were provided with a copy of a birth certificate to support the request. They concluded the birth certificate was fake.

What was Taio Cruz's birth name?

Comment: [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3025511/bio?mode=desktop&ref_=m_ft_dsk) also list his birth name as Adetayo Ayowale Onile-Ere, as does [LastFM](http://www.last.fm/music/Taio+Cruz). Seems to also be some disagreement about when he was born, various sources say 1980 or 1985.

Comment: @user568458 Yes, some sources also say 1983. I guess he updated his age as he got older.

Answer (score 4):

### Proof from independent sources

The [Library of Congress](http://id.loc.gov/authorities/names/no2010087947.html) confirms that this is the legal of Taio Cruz:

> **Onile-Ere, Adetayo Ayowale, 1983-**

Furthermore, [the catalogue of the german national library](https://portal.dnb.de/opac.htm?method=simpleSearch&cqlMode=true&query=idn%3D139766936) confirms that this is his birth name:

> **Shown:** Onile-Ere, Adetayo Ayowale (Wirklicher Name)
>
> **Translation:** Onile-Ere, adetayo Ayowale (Real name)

### Proof from company records

Adetayo Ayowale Onile Ere, born in April 1980, was named as the [Director of a dissolved company named](https://www.companycheck.co.uk/company/05317300/TAIO-CRUZ-INDUSTRIES-LIMITED/directors-secretaries) **Taio Cruz Industries Limited**:

[image]
[image]

### Suspicious birth certificate

[MuricBrainz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MusicBrainz), an open music encyclopedia that collects music metadata and makes it available to the public, [listed his legal name too](https://musicbrainz.org/artist/ba7d2626-38ce-4859-8495-bdb5732715c4):

> **Legal name: Adetayo Ayowale Onile-Ere**

However, the controversy started when in September 2015, [MusicBrainz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MusicBrainz) [received an unusual demand from anti-piracy](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/removals/copyright/domains/musicbrainz.org/) company named [Web Sheriff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Sheriff) who seems to be representing Taio Cruz:

TorrentFreak [gave insights on the demand](https://torrentfreak.com/web-sheriff-sent-forged-taio-cruz-birth-certificate-to-musicbrainz-160309/) :

> Web Sheriff alleged in its demand that a news reporter had erroneously reported Cruz’s name as Adetayo Ayowale Onile Ere “some time ago” and the “error” had gained traction online.

Web Sheriff claimed that, that the issue is causing Taio Cruz “**unnecessary anxiety**”, therefore a “**correction**” would be appreciated.

Skeptical of the company's demand, Robert Kaye, MusicBrainz founder, requested proof of Cruz’s posted legal name to remove the name [from his website](https://blog.musicbrainz.org/2016/03/08/beware-of-the-web-sherriff/), he told Web Sheriff [that](https://blog.musicbrainz.org/2016/03/08/beware-of-the-web-sherriff/):

> If you can provide us with some legal proof that the name is false, we’ll consider making this change.

Two weeks later, he received an alleged copy of a birth certificate said to belong to Cruz. Here is the image he posted on the blog:

[image]

Kaye was not convinced of the authenticity of the document, almost proving that the document is forged, he noted on his blog that:

#### 1. Wrong birth place

The alleged birth certificate claims that he was born in the “county of Westminster”. But a small research shows that the there is no “county of Westminster” but there is a "city of Westminster". This is true verified on this wikipedia page here: [City of Westminster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_Westminster). Searching for *County of Westminster* returns no matches on:

- [Google](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=county+of+westminster&oq=county+of+westminster&gs_l=hp.3..35i39j0j0i22i30l8.498.4091.0.4171.22.18.0.0.0.0.349.2515.0j3j6j2.11.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..11.11.2514.0..46j0i20j0i131i67j0i67j0i131j0i46.2a4zMJ4Mjxc)
- [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=County%20of%20Westminster&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=country%20of%20westminster&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=BCC85CD2C5EE4F0C859E19A99B6B6A77)
- [Yandex](https://yandex.com/search/?text=county%20of%20Westminster&lr=11497)

#### 2. The hospital name is misspelled.

The date and place of birth is listed as:

> Twenty third April 1985 
> Chelsea and Wesminster Hopital, London.

However the hospital name is missing a “t”, it is spelled as **Wesminster**.

#### 3. The hospital was founded after Cruz was born.

Cruz was born in 80s. However, [Chelsea and Westminster Hospital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelsea_and_Westminster_Hospital) was founded in [1993](http://www.chelwest.nhs.uk/about-us):

> Chelsea and Westminster Hospital was built in just five years and opened in 1993, on the site once occupied by St Stephen's Hospital—bringing together staff, services and equipment from five London hospitals.

#### 4. Lawyer does not indicate a profession in the UK

It seems that the word lawyer is not used to describe a profession in the United Kingdom. It is usually describes people who understand the law but not necessarily are real lawyers.  According to [BBC UK](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv79.shtml):

> The word lawyer is a general term and can mean **anyone who gives legal advice** or believes himself learned in one or more areas of law. It is often used to describe solicitors, barristers, legal executives and others - more often than not it is used to describe the whole legal profession.

### Birth Certificate missing from the UK Government

After Kaye received a birth certificate from Web Sheriff (see point above), he [went to a United Kingdom court to attempt to verify the validity of the birth certificate](https://blog.musicbrainz.org/2016/03/08/beware-of-the-web-sherriff/).

He was told by the UK government that they could not verify the authenticity of this certificate, but that he could request a copy of the certificate himself since birth certificates are public record.

Kaye paid the processing fees and requested a copy of the Cruz's birth certificate. However, it was not found. He [reported](https://blog.musicbrainz.org/2016/03/08/beware-of-the-web-sherriff/):

> On November 8th, I received mail from Her Majesty’s government informing me that **no such birth certificate could be found** and that my **payment will soon be refunded**.

He ended saying:

> This strongly suggests that the document provided to us by Web Sheriff was not a legitimate copy of a birth certificate for Jacob Taio Cruz.

### Indication from family trees

Finally, there seems to be a match for a person named **Adetayo Ayowale O A Onile-Ere** on [FamilySearch.org](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QV47-L83N):

[image]

What is worth noting about this match is that Vera Cruz is listed as a mother for **Adetayo Ayowale O A Onile-Ere**.

Comment: Note the certificate says county of westminster not country as in your answer but still the same issue the admin is  Westminster http://www.ukbmd.org.uk/genuki/reg/districts/westminster.html

Comment: Good answer but I'm confused by your "library of congress" entry. It seems to be based on secondary sources like Wikipedia and gives a different birth year to the family search entry (1983 vs 1980).

Comment: @Mark: Can you elaborate your point?

Comment: A mixup of country and county

Comment: @Mark: Fixed...

Comment: Note: The fake birth certificate story is referenced in the question.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Yes I am aware of that.

Comment: You can also see that a different typeface is used on some of the text in the picture of the "birth certificate". Notice that the text "Mother, Father" and "N.F. Morley" looks very different from the other text.

Comment: Good answer, but still no strong evidence. The Library of Congress seem to be based on Wikipedia and other sources and it also gives the incorrect 1983 birth year. The person running Taio Cruz Industries Ltd may be a different person. Same thing with the FamilySearch entry. The fake birth certificate don't prove anything in either direction.

Comment: Regarding Taio Cruz Industries Ltd it says at http://directors.findthecompany.co.uk/l/4188441/Jacob-Taio-Cruz that the director was "Jacob Taio Cruz".